# How to shorten month name in High Sierra menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar, high-sierra

I've updated to High Sierra and one thing that I immediately noticed as an OCD-guy was the full name of the month in menu bar:

[image]

I like keeping things as short as possible and I want to revert it back to the format "Thu 28 Sep 11:08" as in Sierra and below, instead of "28 September Thu 11:08".

I've fiddled with date formats in the system preferences but it doesn't seem to change anything.

How do I get the shorter date back?

Comment: @user770 no, since I tend to get better answers here on StackExchange community.

Comment: @user770 interesting. yes I'd like to see the settings for that. just for clarification: you are on the new OS, High Sierra right?